# How to root a Nexus 10 without wipe?

Tags: rooting, samsung-nexus-10

I would like to root my Nexus 10 without wiping its data so I can later [install Ubuntu Touch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation) on it. How should I do this?

Comment: In addition to the answer, you probably should backup your data if you want to restore it after being wiped.

Answer (score 2):

Rooting a device does not require it to be wiped, although, to root it the device's bootloader needs to be unlocked.  This action requires the device to be wiped.

So, if you have not unlocked the bootloader yet then you need to wipe it, sadly.

If you have unlocked the bootloader then you can root the device without wiping it.

**To root the device** you can use the [Nexus Root Toolkit by Wugfresh](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/).  This is your best option.

Answer (score -1):

Newer versions of SuperSU can achieve root without a custom kernel,You can try to update without wiping your device, although you may encounter problems.

Comment: That's not the problem here... If OP has a locked bootloader he wouldn't even be able to install a custom recovery, let alone SuperSU and stuff; if unlocked then he wouldn't even be asking.